# Display image in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, label, src

I have a class which accesses the database to get an url of an image which is stored in the db. Then it displays the image to the user.

Here is my code behind class:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string image;
        Advertisement Ad= BusinessLogic.getAd(8);

        image = Ad.getImage();
    lblImage.Text = "<img alt='' src='image' />"; 
    }
```

My problem is the image doesn't get displayed in the web form, but if i pass the url directly to the src it works perfectly. I can assure that the stored url link is correct and the url is return using Ad.getImage() method.

Directly passing example:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string image;
        Advertisement Ad= BusinessLogic.getAd(8);

        image = Ad.getImage();
    lblImage.Text = "<img alt='' src='http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/bfeae281284ba5cfd120f41e489eac23/honda-vezel.jpgimage' />";  //directly passed without accessing db
```

}

What can be the problem here?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you check what it is showing in the client side? i.e. in your html source, may be using firebug.

Comment: @mrsrizan I really didn't understand what you meant by firebug. By the way when i view the table data it shows the link url correctly.

Comment: u need an image control n set its source, nt set the text of a label

Comment: @akanksha could you please show how to do it ? thank you for the reply

Comment: I mean please look into the page source. You may find what's wrong. If the url is correctly coming or not in the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think There may be a problem with URL
or Better to use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) (Debugger Tool)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
        string image;
        Advertisement Ad= BusinessLogic.getAd(8);

        image = Ad.getImage();

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('"+image+"');", true);
// it will alert image path
    lblImage.Text = "<img alt='' src='"+image+"' />"; 
}
    }
```